# In terms of performance, do the threads (such as swing threads) "interfere" with my threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm developing a small multi-thread application (in java) to help me understand it. As I researched about it, I learned that the ideal amount of threads you would like the number supported by the processor (ie. 4 in an Intel i3, 8 in an Intel i7, I think). But swing alone already has 3 threads + 1 thread (the main, in this case). Does that means that I won't have any significant improvement in a processor which supports 4 threads? Will the swing threads just consume all the processor threads and everything else will just run on the same processor? Is it worthed to multi-thread it (performance-wise) even with those swing threads?

OBS: A maybe important observation that needs to be made is that I will be using a JFrame and doing active-rendering. That's probably as far as I will go with swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I learned that the ideal amount of threads you would like the number supported by the processor

That statement is only true if your `Thread`s are occupying the whole CPU. For example the Swing thread (Event Dispatch Thread) is most of the time just waiting for user input.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the quoted statement, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The number one thing that most threads do is *waiting*. They are just there so they are ready to go at the instant the system needs their services.

The comment about the ideal thread count goes for the number of threads at 100% workload.

Answer (score 3):

Swing's threads spend a lot of time being idle. The ideal number of threads is wrt threads executing at or near 100% processor time.
You may still not see significant improvements due to other factors, but the threads inherent in swing shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do but only minimally.  There are other threads such as GC and finalizer threads as well that are running in the background.  These are all necessary for the JVM to operate just as the Swing threads are necessary for Swing to work.

You shouldn't have to worry about them unless you are on a dramatically small system with little resources or CPU capacity.

With modern systems, many of which have multiple processors and/or multiple cores, the JVM and the OS will run these other threads on other processors and still give your user threads all of the processor power that you will need.

Also, most of the background Swing threads are in wait loops waiting to handle events and make display changes.  Unless you do something wrong, they should make up a small amount of your application processor requirements.

> I learned that the ideal amount of threads you would like the number supported by the processor

As @Robin mentioned, this is only necessary when you are trying to optimize a program that has a number of CPU-bound operations.  For example, our application typically has 1000s of threads but 8 processors and still is very responsive since the threads are all waiting for IO or events.  The only time you need to worry about the number of CPUs is when you are doing processor intensive operations and you are trying to maximize your throughput.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal # of threads is not necessarily governed by the # of cpu's (cores) you have.  There's a lot of tuning involved base on the actual code you are executing.

For example, let's take a Runnable which executions some database queries (doesn't matter what).  Most of the thread time will be spent blocked waiting for a response from the database.  So if you have 4 cores, and execute 4 threads.  The odds are that at any given time, many of them are blocked on db calls.  You can easily spawn more threads with no ill effects on your cpu.  In this case you're limited not by the specs of your machine, but by the degree of concurrency which the db will handle.

Another example would be file I/O, which spends most of it's time waiting for the I/O subsystem to respond with data.

The only real way is evaluation of your multi-threaded code, along with trial and error for a given environment.